# What happens when software is removed from the Flurry dashboard?

Tags: flurry, flurry-analytics

Several years ago we put Flurry analytics in a few of our games, reporting a selection of events back to us. After a while, when that data was no longer useful to us, we deleted those games from the Flurry dashboard. However, those games are still downloadable with a (very old) version of the Flurry SDK integrated, and with those events still being triggered in game.

We’re updating our privacy policies, and I was wondering if anyone could give us some clarity on what happens with the data from those deleted games. Will information still be sent to Flurry servers, or is there an initialisation step that would detect the games are no longer active on the system and prevent the data being sent? If it is sent, do Flurry's servers still store it or analyse it in any way, or is it ignored as the games aren’t active?

(I've asked Flurry this directly, but their support didn't answer the mail. I'm hoping someone on here might know!)

Thanks,
Rob.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the project is deleted from the dev portal, the sdk still sends data, but it is dropped once it reaches Flurry, and is not stored.